# How to fetch calendar data for a particular date in Google calendar API v3?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-calendar-api

How to fetch calendar data for a particular date in Google calendar API v3?

In parameters, `timeMax` and `timeMin` compares with created date of an event not with the date of occurrence of an event.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

timeMin and timeMax work based on the event date for me. I'm using the api url for events > list. You can run a live test to verify on the [google calendar api docs for events > list](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) at the bottom of the page. Keep in mind that the date format should be yyyy-mm-ddT00:00:00+00:00

Comment: You would think this info would be in the API documentation, huh?

Comment: Thank you Rick for the note about the date format! Also keep in mind that you may need to URL encode the date format. Took me a while to realize that.

Answer (score 3):

Example in php

```
$cal = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
$optParams = array('timeMax' => '2014-12-03T23:59:59+00:00','timeMin' => '2014-12-02T00:00:01+00:00');

$events = $cal->events->listEvents('primary',$optParams);
```